# Drupal 7 Views - How to access unformatted $row variable in a custom template?

Tags: drupal, templates, view

I just installed Views module for Drupal 7 and am trying to find out how to customize it.

So far, I have done the following things.

1. Created a content type specified views and named it as 'videotest'.
2. Created a custom theme as 'views-view-list--videotest.tpl.php'
3. The page is working without a problem.

Here is the custom template code I used (this is the default template from Views):

```
<?php print $wrapper_prefix; ?>
  <?php if (!empty($title)) : ?>
    <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print $list_type_prefix; ?>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
      <li class="<?php print $classes_array[$id]; ?>"><?php print $row; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php print $list_type_suffix; ?>
<?php print $wrapper_suffix; ?>
```

**How do I prevent Views to format $row for me?** I like to format each values in a node myself using foreach.

I tried to set the view style as 'unformatted' with unformatted custom template, but it also style each value for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should to use fields templates not 'Display', 'Style', or 'Row'.

Or you can use both fields in 'Row' template. Ex:

```
print $fields['you_field_value']->raw;
```

Name of 'you_field_value' show as part of link in fields list of view display.

Comment: // it works, but this is not exactly what I was looking for. so..it looks like that the views.view-list.tpl.php is using views-view-fields.tpl.php to display each nodes. Is it possible to access raw values from views.view-list.tpl.php without using views-view-fields.tpl.php?

Comment: Hmm... I think you can use hook_preprocessor_views_view__MY_FIRST_VIEW(&$vars)
Read about this at http://drupal.org/node/303586

Answer (score 2):

Or to get the value of field:

```
print $fields['field_pretitle_front']->content;
```

Comment: I find $fields undefined! I'm using drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

```
print $fields['your_field_value']->raw;
```

did not work for me, however the following did in my case.

```
$row->field_YOUR_FIELD[0]['rendered']['#markup'];
```