# $rows as a pure data model?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drupal 7 Views - How to access unformatted $row variable in a custom template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307416/drupal-7-views-how-to-access-unformatted-row-variable-in-a-custom-template)

I'm overriding a news template which looks like the following:

```
<?php if ($rows): ?>
<div class="view-content">
    <?php print $rows; ?>
</div>
```

What bothers me about this is that the content of `$rows` always has to be a markup-containing element. I'd like to have the pure data-model, without any markup as an array or object.

How can I achieve this? I'm also willing to use other modules than views to achieve an MVC-like templating style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the [`views-view-fields.tpl.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view-fields.tpl.php/7) template instead. This is used for each individual row and gives you the `$fields` array which contains each field in object form.

```
<div class="example-row">
    <span class="example-name"><?php echo $fields['name']->content; ?></span>
    <span class="example-address"><?php echo $fields['field_address_value']->content; ?></span>
</div>
```